# Add a star after labels when input has 'required' attribute

Tags: css

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label for="Description">"Description"</label>
     <input type="text" id="Description" class="form-control"
      [(ngModel)]="description" name="Description"
       required />
 </div>
```

[image]
Is there anyway to add a star **(*)** after label( label::after) **without changing** anything in the code by just adding **CSS** selector?  AFAIK there is no support for previous css selector (has) so I cannot use something like:

```
label:has(+ input:required)::after {
  content:" *";
}
```

Comment: Maybe you could try something with this (8.3.2)? https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#adjacent-sibling-combinators

Comment: the problem with that: (not necessarily immediately)

Comment: Yeah, I don't see how you can target a specific label unless there's something that differentiates it from the others (ergo, changing the code). Maybe a `for` attribute?

Comment: Can't you use javascript to add a class?

Comment: Is there a specific reason, why you can't change the code?

Comment: just being lazy. I don't wanna go and add a class required in labels.  And there are over 200 fields there. I was looking for an easy escape but I can see there is not... And I use a framework to generate crud templates and it generates the code as above..

Comment: Basically,,,**NO**, there isn't.

Answer (score 2):

No.

Via `CSS`-only there is no way to achieve the result without changing markup or javascript in the code **unless**

1) label and input are in the same line, side by side and
2) the background is a solid color

as in the example below, so you could cheat by *always* adding the star, but if the sibling `input` is not `[required]` then cover the star using a `box-shadow`.

```css
input { border: 1px #ccc solid }

label::after {
   content: "*";
   width: 1.5em;
   margin-right: 1.5em;
}

label + input:not([required]) {
   box-shadow: -3.2em 0 0  #fff;
}
```

```html
<label>Username</label>
<input name='username' required />

<br /><br />

<label>Username</label>
<input name='username' />
```

But I'd suggest to at least revert the order of the elements in the markup (and showing them in the right order with `display:flex` and `flex-direction: row-reverse`)

Comment: This is proper cheating :) but the labels are not on the same line with input fields so the covering with box shadow doesn't work. it needs to be again in label..

Comment: Then you should post the actual markup and style with a minimal example, otherwise how can we help you?

Comment: <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="Description">"Description"</label>
                        <input type="text" id="Description" class="form-control"
                            [(ngModel)]="description" name="Description" minlength="1"
                            maxlength="256" required />
                    </div>

Comment: I have updated the question. This hack wouldn't really work for me. There are views as well so i need to find another hack not to add asterisk when labels are used for view etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you are fine with adding a `div` around your every label and input group, then below approach can help you.

```css
input {
  border: 1px #ccc solid
}

input[required]+label::after {
  content: "*";
  color: red;
  width: 1.5em;
  margin-right: 1.5em;
}

.form-group {
   display: flex;
}
.form-group label {
order: -1;
width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <input name='username' required />
  <label>Username</label>
</div>

<br /><br />
<div class="form-group">

  <input name='username' />
  <label>Username</label>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct selector would be

`.form-group:has(:required) label`

But, alas, as the [`:has`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) pseudo class is CSS Selectors Level 4 and has no browser support at all.

You can use it with jQuery though:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $('.form-group:has(:required) label').each((i,el) => {console.log(el); el.classList.add('required')})
})
```

```css
label.required:after {
  content: ' *';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="Description"><span>Description</span></label>
  <input type="text" id="Description" class="form-control"
         name="Description"
         required />
</div>
```

Since you seem to use angular, this might get a little tricky. I don't know, if there is something like this in Angular.

Answer (score 0):

For add '*' after label when input has 'data-val-required' attribute,
you can use java-script with CSS like this:

**CSS:**

```
.required-label::after {
    content: "*";
    color: red;
    margin-right: 0.2em;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="Name" class="form-label"></label>
        <input id="Name" name="Name" class="form-control" />
    </div>
  </div><!-- Col -->
</div><!-- Row -->
```

**JAVA-SCRIPT:**

```
<script>
  var inputs = $('input,textarea,select').filter("[data-val-required]");
  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
      var label = $('label[for="' + inputs[i].name + '"]');
      label.addClass("required-label");
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).